Different output for rpy2.ipython library and default R
Alternative question: RStudio and Jupyter Notebook produces different output
This may look like too trivial QA, but if debug is not easily available within R binary package, it's not a prior knowledge that library actually used stderr instead of expected stdout.
Under raw R (and RStudio) library function prints just progress bar:

....

While under rpy2.ipython (which can be used from Jupyter Notebook) same function outputs extra message and newlines:

R[write to console]: .
R[write to console]: .
R[write to console]: .
R[write to console]: .

What is the reason and how to fix?

It appears to be rpy2.ipython adds extra message when stderr is used under R.
Redirecting to stdout is one of possible fixes:
sink(stdout(), type = "message")
# call library function here

And just in case - for complicated debug cases, mocking output may be handy. There must be a better way to keep base::cat than simply copying it's code, but this worked well for diagnostics too:
original_cat <- function(..., file = "", sep = " ", fill = FALSE, labels = NULL, 
                     append = FALSE){
    if (is.character(file)) 
        if (file == "") 
            file <- stdout()
    else if (startsWith(file, "|")) {
        file <- pipe(substring(file, 2L), "w")
        on.exit(close(file))
    }
    else {
        file <- file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w"))
        on.exit(close(file))
    }
    .Internal(cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append))
}


cat_ex <- function(...){
    # original_cat(...)
    args <- list(...)
    if (!is.null(args[["file"]]))
        args[["file"]] <- NULL
    do.call(original_cat, args)
}


library(testthat)
with_mock(
    cat = cat_ex,
    # call library function here
)

